# Как запретить php отображать содержимое каталога?

Tags: php, html, apache2

В корневой папке Apache2 есть вложенная папка, в которой лежит php-скрипт, с названием, отличным от index.*, например 1.php. Вызываю этот скрипт например через ссылку таким образом: http://localhost/temp/1.php. Все корректно отрабатывает, адрес при этом начинает отображаться в строке адреса. Если отредактировать адрес до http://localhost/temp/ и нажать enter, то браузер отображает все содержимое папки, включая скрипты, графику и т.д., которые можно открывать и запускать. Где в apache или php надо настроить, чтобы из этой папки открывался например только 1.php ?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore

Answer (score 1):

PHP тут ни при чём. Нужно запретить отображение каталога в Web сервере.

В apache это можно сделав создав `.htaccess` файл в этом самом каталоге с содержимым

```
Options -Indexes
```

Либо можно сделать настройку в конфигурации Apache, убрав `Indexes` из конфигурации опций папки:

`/usr/local/httpd/htdocs` - адрес каталога, для которого производится настройка.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs">
  Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

<sub>[Документация](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory)</sub>

Учтите, что при этом остаётся возможным обратиться к файлу внутри каталога напрямую, не отображая содержимое каталога.

---

Можно также переименовать `1.php` в `index.php` (и не трогать `Options`). Тогда при обращении к папке `/temp`, файл `1.php` должен выполниться автоматически, при условии, что опция `DirectoryIndex` содержит `index.php`.

<sub>[Документация](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)</sub>

Comment: Поместил в каталог файлик .htaccess с указанным содержимым, но содержимое каталога по-прежнему отображается в броузере. При этом сам файлик .htaccess, лежащий в каталоге, не отображается

Comment: @Pustota, попробуйте создать в каталоге пустой файл `index.html`

Comment: Создал, и если он не пустой то он загружается как страница. Если совсем пустой - то пустая белая страница

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы там только `1.php` отображалось? Тогда добавьте в `index.html` -> `<a href="http://localhost/temp/1.php">Вам сюда</a>`

Comment: 1.php это частность. Я хотел только узнать, как предотвратить в броузере отображение содержимого каталога, если в нем отсутствует index.*